# Dict type throws error in json.dumps

Tags: python, json, dictionary, typeerror

I am passing a dictionary to `json.dumps` and it is still throwing an error:

```
TypeError: Undefined is not json serializable
```

I even check the type before calling the function to make sure it is a dictionary type.I'm using the Flask microframework and trying to return a Response object containing really simple json to an ajax request:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$.getJSON($SCRIPT_ROOT + '/getDictionary', function(data) {

    console.log(data);

});
```

});

```
@app.route('/getDictionary')

def getDictionary():

    empty_dic = {'empty' : 'dict'}

    if type(empty_dic) is dict:
        return Response(json.dumps(empty_dic), mimetype = "application/json")
```

Comment: I tried running your code and got `SyntaxError: 'return' outside function`. [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) please :-)

Comment: You're clearly using some kind of web framework here, and showing us a fragment of a handler function for that framework, given that `return Response(…)` bit. So you'll have to tell us _which_ framework. And, as @Kevin says, give us a complete example. Which includes the complete traceback. (My guess here is that the framework is actually trying to do some JSON stuff, and the exception is coming from inside the framework, not your own probably-unwanted `json.dumps`, but that's no more than a guess based on the paltry information you've given us.)

Comment: Also, there's a whole slew of errors in this code—`emptyDic` vs. `emptydic` should give you a `NameError` if you're lucky, or use some completely different object if you're not; `.encoded('utf8')` instead of `.encode` will definitely give you an `AttributeError`; etc. Get your example down to the one error you're actually asking about, or nobody can even debug that one error for you.

Answer (score 1):

Your capitalization is off, note you define `emptydic` but try to serialize `emptyDic`. Try this:

```
empty_dict = {'simple' : 'dict'}

if type(empty_dict) is dict:
    return Response(json.dumps(empty_dict).encoded('utf8'), mimetype = "application/json")
```

Note it's also against [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#method-names-and-instance-variables) to use camel case for variables. Snake case is recommended

Comment: Sorry, I updated my question. the emptyDic vs emptydic was an error when asking the question rather than in the code itself

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example that works:

```
import json

emptydic = {'simple' : 'dict'}

if isinstance(emptydic, dict):    # Note capitalization
    print(json.dumps(emptydic))   # {"simple": "dict"}
```

The type checking condition has changed slightly, and I stripped the `Response`/`mimetype` stuff, because it seems orthogonal to your issue.

Comment: If that works, then the error would have to lie in the Response object being returned I'm guessing.

Comment: @kag359six Most likely the error is being caused by the creation of the `Response` object.  A full traceback would be able to confirm this.

Answer (score 0):

Your dictionary has name "emptydic"

In the condition, you use "emptyDic"

Try:

```
emptyDic = {"simple": "dict"}

if type(emptyDic) is dict:
    return Response(json.dumps(emptyDic).encoded('utf8'), mimetype = "application/json")
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying this by any chance

```
json.dumps(emptydic, encoding='utf-8')
```

I am trying this on Python 2.7 and the string object will not have an attribute called encoded.

Comment: I have tried it without the encoding argument altogether and it still does not work in its most basic form.